# VBA Copy and Paste Macro which Loops

Tags: vba, copy, range, paste

New to VBA and simply wanted to create a macro which copies the tables within a specified range and pastes in the next available empty rows. What happens is that every time I run it it pastes into the same range i.e. B12 and don't know how to amend...

```
Sub CopyRange2()

Range("A1:I9").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B12").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Would like to know why you have specified cell B12 ??

The below code will work if you just want to paste the data in the next available empty rows.

```
Sub CopyRange2()

Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A1:I9").Select
Selection.Copy

Range("A" & lastrow + 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works, but the pointless selects should be avoided as best practice, particularly if beginners are going to copy+paste. The following 4 lines are equivalent, unfortunately I can't format in comment

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A1:I9").Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Range("A" & lastrow + 1)